# ActiveRecord complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a problem with finding best selling books. I have next models:
Book

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :books_categories

  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

BooksCategory

```
class BooksCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Category

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

OrderItem

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :book
end
```

and Order

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, through: :order_items
end
```

So I need to find the best selling book from each category. The book is considered sold when the order has status 2 or 3. I wrote next code:

```
  def best_sellers
    books_ids = []

    Category.all.each do |category|
      temp_hash = OrderItem.joins(book: :books_categories)
        .where(books: { books_categories: { category: category } })
        .joins(:order).where(orders: { status: [2, 3] })
        .group(:book_id).sum(:quantity)

      books_ids << temp_hash.key(temp_hash.values.max)
    end

    Book.where(id: books_ids)
  end
```

It works but it's not optimized. Can you help me to combine all this lines into one query without cycle and without raw SQL?